# EmberJS-issue with uppercase letters in model properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I created a fiddle below that replicates the error. Basically, the api I'm consuming has all its model properties starting with uppercase and for some reason Ember doesn't seem to like it. The issue is mainly when there is a nested object with a leading uppercase property as below `contact.CommunicationInfo.MobilePhoneNo`

```
contact: {
            CommunicationInfo: {
                MobilePhoneNo: '2323232'
            }
         }
```

Now when I'm transitioning into a child route which uses the same model, Ember throws this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CommunicationInfo' of undefined` I can override the default model properties to lowercase but what I'm not sure is if it's bug in Ember itself or am I doing it wrong?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VmZ2U/1/

Click '`Go to Contacts`' and click '`Go to details`' while inspecting the console. If I uncomment the 2 lines in the contacts model, everything works fine.

Comment: issue is not because of casing..its somehow rendering contacts/index when you even go to contacts/details..if you remove this line `Phone: {{contact.CommunicationInfo.MobilePhoneNo}}` from template, it runs well which proves my point..

Comment: @CodeJack You are right. It is not the casing but it might be because this specific property is one level deeper than the rest. I tried adding a new property in the same level as 'MobilePhoneNo' but with a lowercase and it still fails. Shall I open an issue in Ember's github repo?

Comment: yea it looks weird...i actually expected that it may be rendering `index` first and then `details`. so i tried to create new route but still getting same error...http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cuman/3/edit ...i have same kinda routes in one of my projects but didn't face any this kind issue..